# Div not centering as expected

Tags: html, css, alignment

I'm trying to center the inner divs by setting the margins on the outer div, but it does not appear to be working.

So my HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="outer">
<div class="inner"><span>H</span></div>
<div class="inner"><span>I</span></div>
</div>
```

My CSS looks something like this:

```
#outer {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto; /* This is not working for some reason */
}

#outer .inner {
  display: inline-block; /* Used to put the boxes side by side */
  margin: 0 0 0 1%;
  width: 5%;
}
```

I can't figured out what is wrong with my CSS code. Even if I set a fixed width, it still won't center.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `text-align: center` css property in your `#outer` div to center `.inner` divs (as they are `display`ed as *inline* elements).

```css
#outer { text-align:center; }
#outer .inner { display: inline-block;width: 5%; }
```

```html
<div id="outer">
   <div class="inner"><span>H</span></div>
   <div class="inner"><span>I</span></div>
</div>
```